# htaccess to redirect domain, except one subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I have domain.net and store.domain.net.

I need to have everything under domain.net to redirect to newdomain.com.  But, I want store.domain.net to remain unchanged, and not forward.

Also, all paths remain the same.  ie: domain.net/category/post123 is the same contents as newdomain.com/category/post123.

I was thinking I could do this via an htaccess with a simple 302 redirect, but having the exception was giving me problems.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^store\.domain\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?domain\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%1newdomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```